# Fiddler periodically receives alien communications

Tags: fiddler

While running Fiddler, I occasionally get clusters of gibberish sessions, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHX41.png).

I have seen this at my old job, as well as at my new job at an entirely different company.

Unless I am personally being tracked by space aliens, I'm curious if anyone else has seen this, or know what causes these periodic clusters of connections to nonexistent domain names. I reliably see them when switching networks, if that helps.

Comment: I suspect this is this phenomenon: http://superuser.com/questions/478848/using-chrome-and-fiddler-showed-strange-requests-what-is-it

Comment: While questions about programming Fiddler, or about writing programs that interact with Fiddler, are acceptable on this site, other questions about it are best directed elsewhere, possibly to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @JohnChristensen: Yup, looks like this is a duplicate. Thanks for pointing out that link!

Answer (score 3):

*Holy sh#t, call the feds!*

More seriously, let me try to explain  the origin of those requests:

In one hand, some ISPs use some sort of DNS spoofing to redirect URLs like `http://yoursearchterms` into something like `http://yourisp.com/search?terms=yoursearchterms`.

But in the other hand, Google Chrome uses the URL bar as both a URL bar and a search bar.

Conflict of interest you would say, but Chrome doesn't give up that easy.

To work out that problem, Chrome sends on startup three `HEAD` requests to random URLs (like the ones shown in your screen capture) to check if your ISP uses DNS spoofing, and adapt its behavior accordingly.

No aliens

*Source: https://github.com/darwin/chromium-src-chrome-browser/blob/master/intranet_redirect_detector.cc line 78*